# How to see the Error Panel in Xcode when build fails?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode11, swift5

How can xcode can switch to the error pane when building or running fails because of an error in my code?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgK71.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode preferences select the Behaviours tab, the select "Fails" in the Build box. On the right select Show Navigator and set to "Issue Navigator";[image]